# configparser.ParsingError: Source contains parsing errors: 'my.ini'

Tags: python

I am getting this error: `configparser.ParsingError: Source contains parsing errors: 'my.ini'`
although I am getting uncommented-values printed on the terminal.

**`my.ini`:**

```
[my]
# user
root
# passwd
password
```

I read [here](https://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) that `#` or `;` could be used for commenting. This is how I am doing it:

```
import configparser

c = configparser.ConfigParser()
c.read('my.ini')
getval = c.items('my')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is `root` and `password` don't have a value assigned to them. Since it appears that you want to allow that, just say so when you create the `ConfigParser` instance:

```
c = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
```

Or in Python 2:

```
c = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
```

Comment: Yes, checked that, it's working ! Now, I'm getting values without any errors on terminal.

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the same issue, but the below line resolves the error the as same above one.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is the same as mine.